# How to make a LED bar display a binary value?

Tags: led, digital-logic, binary

I have a 5-bit binary number from 0 to 11110 (30 decimal). I want to display it in a led bar using "bar" mode. It means that if the number is 10000 (see the picture below) I want ALL 16 leds from the first to 16-th be on. The circuit below turns on only one led corresponding to the input number.
How can I make it?
[image]

Update:
I ended up using 74HC238 as 3 to 8 bit decoder + 29 logical OR elements (7432 IC).

Comment: Start again is my advice. Looks like you went down the wrong path when you chose the LS138 IMHO. I mean you could bodge it with some steering diodes and buffers but. it's probably not worth it.

Comment: You COULD fix this. Start by formulating precisely what you want from each LED. Such as ... I want each LED to be ON if the index is its number **OR** any higher numbered LED is on. Then see if that helps you design logic to fulfil that problem statement.

Comment: This is a sort of *ugly* problem.  Perhaps there's a specific chip for this task, but that seems not all that likely.  You could do it with custom logic in a CPLD.  Realistically in the real world you'd probably do this with an MCU, but while it *could be* your input then would probably not be a parallel binary word, but rather a value passed from a software version of the previous stage, too.  What is your actual goal here, and why are you trying to do it at this legacy level of integration?

Comment: I have a binary up-down counter (2 cascaded 4-bit counters), which stores timer interval - number of minutes. This is a home project and I use simple IC-s just for educational purposes.

Comment: The logic port arrangement for this is awful. Use a MCU to control the 74LS138's; it is a intermediate **and** educational solution that let you use the old 74LS138, but keeps you from this task of combining dozens of logical ports (and build a large circuit) for doing this.

Comment: If you post your update as an answer you can accept it (in a day or two, I think) which will mark the question as solved.